# Twice refreshed in p:commandButton, race condtition with oncomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm executing the server action with `p:commandButton`. After those action is completed, I'm refreshing the form (to show hidden fields) and I show dialog. I've tried also to refresh only the panels with hidden buttons, but the effect was the same:

There is second refresh launched, after I call `dialog.show().` The problem is, that the widgets defined inside the dialog and the dialog itself is not existing in the moment! So, when my JavaScript code runs too fast, before the post with update of the dialog finishes, I'm getting an exception, because the object I want to modify doesn't exist in DOM tree.

So my first question, is it possible to avoid such situation and second refresh, can't the dialog be refreshed along with page?

And second, if the first can't be answered, how can I launch my code **after** those second post finishes? I need simply a callback when refreshing of the dialog component will be completed, and than run my operations.

```
    <p:commandButton id="doTask" value="Do task" widgetVar="doTaskButton"
        action="#{service.doTask}" update="@form"
        onclick="disableMainButtons()"
        oncomplete="async.showAsyncDialog()" />
```

The HTTP sequence:

```
// button click
POST http://localhost:9080/myapp/order.xhtml 200 OK
// oncomplete launches dialog.show()
// I receive answer from COMET before the dialog to display it is shown
POST http://localhost:9080/myapp/channel/async 200 OK
// refresh triggered by dialog.show(), only now the dialog is shown and it's widgets are rendered
POST http://localhost:9080/myapp/order.xhtml 200 OK
```

Comment: To the technical sense, I have no idea why PrimeFaces are doing that, nor I have influence on it.

Comment: No, because, at least as far as I've understood, primefaces push doesn't work without additional libraries, that would involve JBoss licence (I'm using websphere) and the use case is trivial (display background task progress and enable close button after finished) I've made it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround, that isn't beautiful from programming point of view is to check if the dialog is rendered and if not, delay my procedure. In case the dialog is still not rendered, delay once again etc.

```
waitForDialogRendered: function() {
    var visible = asyncDialog.jq.css('visibility') == 'visible';
    if (!visible) {
        setTimeout(waitForDialogRendered, 250);
        return;
    }
    runComet();
}
```

Not that `asyncDialog.jq.is(':visible')` returns `true` even if dialog is not visible for user!

Still, I'd be happier without the need to write such code.